# Can you sheathe your weapon in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I've just started playing Borderlands 2, and for whatever reason, I'm finding myself constantly waving a gun about no matter what I'm doing.

I'd like to be able to put the gun away while I'm just wandering around looting crates and whatnot. I know the violence doesn't stop for extended periods of time, but that's not important.

**Can I sheathe my weapon in Borderlands 2? If so, what is the default control?** (I've tried mashing all the buttons on my controller (playing on PC, using xbox 360 controller) but I can't get it to happen.)

Comment: Mashing buttons is always the best start, then swearing, then stack exchange! You can't as the others have said, and it's very annoying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The closest you can get to putting your weapon away is completely unequipping it.

Comment: Completely uneqipping *all of them*. Later in the game, when you have 4 gun slots, that becomes... cumbersome. Plus, then you still get flying hands, which personally irritate me more than any gun :)

Answer (score 4):

I tend to equip very small weapons when I am just running around. Some weapons are so small that when you are running, they completely leave your field of view. You'll have to experiment to see what weapons work the best, but pistols and SMGs tend to be the smallest weapons in the game.